# Virtualenv Env Permission denied with Pyenv Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

Tried creating a virtual environment with python2 which is not the system default in MacOS 14 Beta.  Python2 was installed through pyenv. Ends up hitting a permission error.

```
➜  test_py3 virtualenv -p /Users/b/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18 my_py2
RuntimeError: failed to query /Users/b/.pyenv/versions/2.7.18 with code 13 err: 'Permission denied'
```

Virtualenv was installed by

```
pip3 install --user virtualenv
```

Expected it to create a python virtual env with python installed through pyenv.